# Can someone tell about this new HACK programming language from facebook

Tags: javascript, hacklang

I cant find many resources about it on the internet. I would like too look into this more and what similarities does it have with javascript!

Answer (score 3):

It's not very Javascriptlike at all.  It's more like PHP + static type annotations.  It compiles to the HipHop Virtual Machine, for which Facebook has a JIT PHP compiler as well.

The resources that exist publicly are all at [hacklang.org](http://hacklang.org).